# TypeScript with express, nodemon & jest --watch

Tags: typescript, express, jestjs

I've got just set up just fine, I can run `jest` and my unit tests are run. I've also get tsc-watch keeping an eye on my changes and compiling when I run `yarn dev` the below script in package.json is triggered.

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc-watch --project . --outDir ./dist --onSuccess \"nodemon ./dist/app.js\"",
  },
```

Is there some way I can have jest constantly watching at the same time, so if I break a test as I'm coding it will tell me immediately?

My jest.config.js looks like

```
module.exports = {
    roots: ['<rootDir>/tests'],
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    testRegex: '(/tests/.*|(\\.|/)(test))\\.tsx?$',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  }
```

and my tsconfig.js

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": ["api/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "tests/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: What about running Jest watcher in another terminal?

Comment: yes that's what I'm doing now, it's ok but it would be nice to have both running in one

Comment: You can try to run multiple npm scripts with concurrently.